# Como usar chave estrangeira para criar um registro em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Eu tenho duas tabelas `users` e `users_info`, gostaria de usar chave estrangeira, para quando eu criasse um registro na tabela `users`, criasse um registro com os campos vazios na tabela `users_info`, apenas com o `id_user` preenchido, é possivel?

Comment: pra criar outro registro, você precisará de uma trigger

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Conseguiria me dar um exemplo de como faria?

Comment: acredito que já tenha a resposta abaixo. =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que ficaria assim, lembre-se que os campos da tabela `user_info` devem permitir valores nulos.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_user
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO user_info (id_user, outro_campo, exemplo)
  SELECT NEW.id, NULL, NULL
  FROM users
  WHERE id = NEW.id
```

Comment: Vou testar e ja te dou um feedback ;)